# Printing after certain time has elapsed

Tags: python-2.7

I am a beginner with Python, and I am trying to make a code where after a certain amount of time has passed, it will print the elapsed time. This probably seems like an easy question, but I;m having trouble.  Here is the code:

```
    from time import time  
    start=time()  
    y=1

    while (y==1):  
        if time()-start>2000000000:  
            print time()  
            y=y+1  
        else:  
            print"???"
```

All I get back are the question marks. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to wait over 63 years before you will see `print time()` being output instead of question marks.

`time()` outputs the time in *seconds* since the epoch. 2,000,000,000 (2 billion) seconds is a  long time to wait! If you start it now, it'll be done on the 17th of april, 2076.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `print "???"` with `pass`, or completely remove the `else:` clause, and the code will work (once you change the waiting period to a more reasonable value).

However, your loop will spend 100% of the available CPU power. So it is a good idea to replace `print "???"` with a small sleep, such as `time.sleep(.01)`.

Also, you can use a `while True` loop and exit the loop with `break`, which will remove the need for the `y` variable.